# No puedo conectarme a mi servidor en red sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema: Me estoy conectando a mi servidor sql server (uso sql server 2014) y se logra conectar usando la direccion ip del servidor (ejm. 192.168.1.x\SQLEXPRESS). Pero cuando intento conectarme con usando el nombre del servidor (ejm. MiServer\SQLEXPRESS) no conecta. Sale el error numero 26 que dice que no se encontró el servidor o no estaba accesible. Cabe decir que he configurado el servidor para admitir conexiones remotas y tambien esta configurado el SQLBrowser. Tambien está habilitado el puerto 1433. El firewall de windows tambien esta configurado para permitir la conexion a traves del puerto. Como dato adicional: Si desactivo el firewall de windows ahi si puedo ingresar. Espero me puedan ayudar...Gracias

Comment: Supongo que en el firewall tendrás que autorizar el acceso al puerto 1433 de forma explícita. Si dices que funciona cuando desactivas el corta fuegos es evidente que está bloqueando ese puerto.

Answer (score 1):

Has habilitado las canalizaciones con nombre? lo puedes encontrar en SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER -> Configuración de Red de SQL Server -> Protocolos de SQLEXPRESS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres también puedes copiar lo siguiente en un archivo bat y ejecutarlo como administrador en el servidor. Te abre todos los puertos del SQL por si se te ha quedado alguno.

```html
@echo =========  SQL Server Ports  ===================
@echo Enabling SQLServer default instance port 1433
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLServer"
@echo Enabling Dedicated Admin Connection port 1434
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1434 "SQL Admin Connection"
@echo Enabling conventional SQL Server Service Broker port 4022
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 4022 "SQL Service Broker"
@echo Enabling Transact-SQL Debugger/RPC port 135
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 135 "SQL Debugger/RPC"
@echo =========  Analysis Services Ports  ==============
@echo Enabling SSAS Default Instance port 2383
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2383 "Analysis Services"
@echo Enabling SQL Server Browser Service port 2382
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2382 "SQL Browser"
@echo =========  Misc Applications  ==============
@echo Enabling HTTP port 80
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 80 "HTTP"
@echo Enabling SSL port 443
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 443 "SSL"
@echo Enabling port for SQL Server Browser Service's 'Browse' Button
netsh firewall set portopening UDP 1434 "SQL Browser"
@echo Allowing multicast broadcast response on UDP (Browser Service Enumerations OK)
netsh firewall set multicastbroadcastresponse ENABLE
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Complementado lo que dice el colega @Juanjo también me ha pasado que algún servicio del SQL no está corriendo.